Duplicate class found in modules. Java for android
I'm currently working on an Android application, which will operating with different devices. It will contain some .jar files and it should choose which .jar to use depending on which device it is installed. Jar files contain some classes, that are named exactly the same, but have different behavior. The problem i have encountered is that my project can't be built due to "Duplicate class found" error. Duplicate error
.jar structure
build.gradle.kts
My MainActivity code looks like this:MainActivity.java
I tried using DexClassLoader and it worked perfectly with only one package implemented. But the problem occurs on build stage.

You need to configure build variants for your app.
checkout the docs for it.
https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants

Each build variant represents a different version of your app that you
can build. For example, you might want to build one version of your
app that's free with a limited set of content, and another paid
version that includes more. You can also build different versions of
your app that target different devices, based on API level or other
device variations

check this SO thread for how to.
android-library with specific Product Flavors dependency
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
    }
}

dependencies {
    flavor1Compile ...
}

you can select the desired build variant (profile) from Android Studio. Each build variant will use its own configuration you have in the build.gradle file.

Thank you. This solution works pretty good. I have created two flavors, and added different dependencies to them. But now I have to create two different builds and provide each device with a certain one. Is there a way for the program to be more autonomous? Can I create a managing program that will identify the device and call the right build after that?

If you plan to distribute your app through platforms like the Google Play Store or other app stores, they typically offer configuration settings allowing you to specify conditions for installing your application on devices. This means you can generate multiple builds and distribute them through the app store, each customizedto meet specific conditions.
